# How does this function return the first dupe from an array?

Tags: php

I have a task (or more like a challenge) found on Code-Signal (a site where do you can do some programming-related tasks. This special task was asked by google in an interview:

If you want to try it for yourself: [Code-Fight](https://app.codesignal.com/interview-practice/task/pMvymcahZ8dY4g75q/).

After solving an issue, you are allowed to see other solutions.

My task was "find the first dupe in an array". I managed to do this (i'll show the way), but I'm not happy with my result. After investigating the top-solutions, I was confused, since I don't understand whats going on there.

This was (a) given example input array

```
$a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]
```

**My solution:**

```
function firstDuplicate($a) {

    $onlyDupesArray= array();
    $countedValues = array_count_values($a);

    // remove all entries which are only once in the array
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if($countedValues[$v] > 1) {
            $onlyDupesArray[$v] = $v;
        }
    }

    // get rid of dupes
    $uniqueDupesArray = array_unique($onlyDupesArray);
    $firstEncounter = PHP_INT_MAX;

    foreach($uniqueDupesArray as $k => $v) {
        if(array_keys($a, $v)[1] < $firstEncounter) {
            $firstEncounter = array_keys($a, $v)[1];
        }
    }

    if(is_null($a[$firstEncounter])) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return $a[$firstEncounter];
    }
}
```

It works in every test-case and I solved the challenge. However, the top-solution was this:

```
function firstDuplicate($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v)
        if ($$v++) return $v;
    return -1;
}
```

I know what a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is, but haven't seen this in the wild-life yet until now.

What does the references variable do here? How is this returning a dupe? Does it somehow compare if there is already a value for a key with this typing? Does `$$v++` reference a key in an array?

Needlessly to say, I like this approach muche more. It seems way more efficient and better to maintain.

Is this "common practice"?

Comment: Not a very good "top" solution: https://repl.it/repls/CrimsonSphericalForm

Comment: I kinda agree, but it *does* indeed print the correct output. 1 is the first dupe in your example and that is printed. Yes, there is a warning, but it seems like they don't look at that.

Comment: It emits warnings and isn't what I'd classify as readable. Sure, it's at least somewhat interesting, but wouldn't call it "better to maintain" or more "efficient" than some alternatives.

Comment: Also no, $$v++ does not have any relation to a key in the array.

Comment: @Script47 voted to the top by people who prefer to code with `error_reporting=0` in php.ini, no doubt. but still clever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is creating numbered variables. $2, $1, $3 etc.

$v in the foreach contains the current number, 2. By doing `$test = 2; echo $$test` we can see what is in $2 right now. It is normally empty. Now, by doing $$v++, it will return the current value (empty, or actually, variable does not exist), but ++ will put '1' in it. The whole statement itself will return 0, since ++ is not in front of the variable.

Consider this code:

```
$arr = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2];
foreach($arr as $v) 
{
  $$v++;
}
$test = 3; 
echo $$test;
```

It will show that the value of $3 equals 2, because we did 2 times ++ on $3.

The only reason this is weird is that normally you can't use variables starting with numbers. Maybe this makes it clearer?:

```
$arr = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]; 
foreach($arr as $v) 
{
  $v='a'.$v;
  $$v++;
}
echo "a3 = $a3\n"; // 2
echo "a2 = $a2\n"; // 2
echo "a1 = $a1\n"; // 1
echo "a5 = $a5\n"; // 1
```

To answer the question "Is this "common practice"?". No, I would personally not use variable variables, as this can in some cases been considered as a security problem. I personally like the following solution better, which is the same, but uses an array, and does not throw notices:

```
function firstDuplicate($a) {
    $arr = []; 
    foreach ($a as $v) 
        if (in_array($v, $arr))
            return $v; 
        else
            $arr[] = $v; 
    return -1; 
}
```

The variable variables solution is a creative one, though!

Answer (score 0):

By specifying your variable with an additional $ (variables variable) PHP creates a "hidden/fake array".
While running each index gets filled with a "0":

After the first run you got something like

```
$array[2] = 0;
```

After the next run the index 1 gets filled:

```
$array[1] = 0;
$array[2] = 0;
```

Since a "0" is treated as false, your condition becomes valid after the first duplicate (3):

```
$array[1] = 0;
$array[2] = 0;
$array[3] = 1; // <-- TRUE
$array[5] = 0;
```

Comment: `PHP creates a "hidden" array. ` O_o

Comment: `PHP creates a "hidden/fake" array` O_o

Comment: I hate it, when PHP creates hidden / fake arrays

Comment: PHP creates a "hidden" array.

Comment: If by hidden / fake array, you mean a real variable (which is where the Undefined Variable warnings come from). And without a value, the default is `null`. And after the `$$v++` the value is already `1`.